# Remove Unselected Regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I am still new about programming and need your help.
I have searched and tried about my case, that i want to remove some string on java, but i dont know how to make its regex.
So my case is :

```
"Square Tower, John Febrian, Public Transportation"
```

and want to make it to :

```
"Square Tower, John Febrian"
```

what regex should i use if i want to split, replace, or change the last word after second comma with my java code x.split or x.replace ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one way to do it:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourString = "Square Tower, John Febrian, Public Transportation";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^([^,]+,[^,]+),").matcher(yourString);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        String wantedString = matcher.group(1);
        // Output: 'Extraction: "Square Tower, John Febrian"'
        System.out.println("Extraction: \"" + wantedString + "\"");
    }
}
```